# Django filter based in joined table

Tags: django, django-models

I have two tables:

```
class Client(models.Model):
    name = models.TextField()
    lastname = models.TextField()

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'client'

class Clientreport(models.Model):
        id_client_home = models.ForeignKey('Client', models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='id_client_home', related_name='home_id_client_home')
        id_client_reported = models.ForeignKey('Client', models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='id_client_reported', related_name='client_id_client_home')

        class Meta:
            managed = False
            db_table = 'clientreport'
```

And I'm trying to build a query similar to this:

```
SELECT cr.*, cl.id, cl.name, cl.lastname FROM Clientreport cr INNER JOIN Client cl ON cr.id_client_reported = cl.id 
WHERE (LOWER(cl.name) LIKE LOWER('%jo%') OR LOWER(cl.lastname) LIKE LOWER('%jo%') )
```

I tried using:
[SQL queries](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/sql/)

But, now I'm trying to do it using django.
How I can access to a joined model using django???

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can query across joins using standard Django Queryset filters, using `__` to go across the relationship like this:

```
Clientreport.objects.filter(client_id_client_home__name='jo')
```

`client_id_client_home` being the `related_name` from your `Clientreport` model. More info here in the documentation on [queries using related objects](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/queries/#related-objects).

To reproduce the `LIKE LOWER('%jo%')` you can use [`__icontains`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/querysets/#icontains):

```
Clientreport.objects.filter(client_id_client_home__name__icontains='jo')
```

Comment: Awesome! thanks! I didn't know about the `__` to go across the relationships. Thanks @Gavin Clark